# django web app deployment on windows 10 using apache server(WAMP) not displaying CSS for admin site

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, wamp

On Windows 10 django app when run using development server by using command python manage.py runserver shows admin login page  and admin site correctly. but if same django app at same path when served using apache is not displaying css  correctly for admin login and other admin site pages.

I have tried to  follow steps at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ but some configuration/setting is missed/incorrect resulting in css not applied to admin login page and admin site.
my development and deployment is on same windows 10 computer with WAMP server 3.2.3.3.
I have installed mod_wsgi  and following are relevent section from settings.py
import os
from pathlib import Path

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent




# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secrete key is listed here'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'hellodjangodeployapache_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'hellodjangodeployapache_project.wsgi.application'


# Database


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

SITE_ID = 1
# Internationalization


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type

    enter code here

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

my projects urls.py looks like as below

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
                  path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('', views.home, name='home'),

              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

wsgi.py is as below

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hellodjangodeployapache_project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

django project directory structure is as shown in picture below

[project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5vjU.png)

following lines are added to httpd.conf of apache server

```
# LoadFile "d:/pythoninstallation/python39.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/admin/envs/hellodjangodeployapacheenv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp39-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/users/admin/envs/hellodjangodeployapacheenv"


WSGIPythonPath "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project"

<Directory "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

Alias /media/ "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/media/"

Alias /static/ "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/static/"

<Directory "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/static/">
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/media/">
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/hellodjangodeployapache_project/wsgi.py"

<Directory "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/hellodjangodeployapache_project">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

following is httpd-vhosts.conf file content

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
#  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
#    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
#    AllowOverride All
#    Require local
#  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wamp server is installed at C:\wamp64 and content of C:\wamp64\www is empty.
virtual envirornment is created using virtualenvwrapper-win and its name is hellodjangodeployapacheEnv.

when django webpapp is run using python manage.py runserver  and opened using http://127.0.0.1:8000 it shows admin login page/admin site properly but it is served apache with above mentioned configuration settings http://localhost/admin shows admin login page and admin site without css.
what is change is needed in above mentioned settings/ configuration files so that admin login/ admin site shows normal CSS when served using apache server on windows 10.?

Comment: please checkout this https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoAdminCSSNotWorking/

Comment: I  have used command python manage.py collectstatic but still it shows css for admin site when served using apache server

Comment: You are adding the MEDIA_URL to the urlpatterns, but you are not adding the STATIC_URL. Define a STATIC_URL as you do with MEDIA_URL and add it to urlpatterns like you do with the MEDIA. By the way, these are only needed for development, so you could add them only when settings.DEBUG = True.

Comment: as suggested by Marc Compte I have updated urlpatterns with settings.STATIC_URL   as urlpatterns = [
                  path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('', views.home, name='home'),

              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)  but still it does not serve css for admin . code is expected to work with Debug=False in settings.py. Is there any other change I should make

Comment: it shows css for admin site when admin directory from  \hellodjangodeployapacheEnv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static is copied to static directory at D:\djangoprojects\hellodjangodeployapache\hellodjangodeployapache_project\static but https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoAdminCSSNotWorking/ says But that's an ugly hack, and you'll soon run into problems with the rest of your CSS not loading. if there is better solution pl  suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Apache config, the static alias must point towards your static_root folder
hence it will look like

`Alias /static/ "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/staticfiles/"`

Comment: as suggested by  S.H. following change is made in httpd.conf file  but it does not shows css for admin site  #Alias /static/ "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/static/"
Alias /static/ "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/staticfiles/"

Comment: did u try to run collectstatic? and ik it sounds silly.. but did u restart the server? also your string needs to change inside <Directory ...path-to-static-root >Require all granted </Directory>

Comment: ran collectstatic & restrated server,it worked after following change  in httpd.conf file 
Alias /static/ "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/staticfiles/"
<Directory "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/static/">
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/staticfiles/">
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "D:/djangoprojects/hellodjangodeployapache/hellodjangodeployapache_project/media/">
Require all granted
</Directory>